# Regex with a match between quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to find a solution to my RegEx problem, but I cannot find an answer.

My target string is like this:

```
"Elevator" <sip:103@192.168.1.1>;tag=343483547
```

I want my matching groups to be:
- Elevator
- 103

But when I use this regex:

```
"(.*)"?<sip:(\d*)@.*
```

then I get an unwanted quote with my 1st match. It results in:
- Elevator"
- 103

I can't get it to work. I tried the most obvious things like

```
"([^"]*)"?<sip:(\d*)@.*
```

but then the first match vanishes completely

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Whence is the `103` value in your expected result?  Your input does not contain this information.

Comment: Try `"([^"]*)"?\s*<sip:(\d*)@.*`. There is a whitespace between `"` and `<`, so you need to account for it in the pattern.

Comment: The squared brackets in the target string conflicted with thml. I changed it to 'code'

Comment: It was indeed the ?s* that did the trick, Thanks @WiktorStribiżew
Make it an answer, so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the whitespace between an optional `"` and the following `<` char.

Use

```
"([^"]*)"?\s*<sip:(\d*)@.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YyXSX4/2)

**Details**

- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `<sip:` - `<sip:` substring
- `(\d*)` - Group 2: zero or more (replace `*` with `+` to match one or more) digits
- `@.*` -  a `@` and the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the `"` optional and the `.*` is greedy matching until the `<` is encountered.

If the quote is unwanted, you could update it to make the " not optional and match the space before the `<`.

The `"(.*?)"` part can also be matched as `([^"]+)`

If you want to match 1 or more digits use `\d+`

```
"(.*?)" <sip:(\d+)@
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28.*%3f%29%22+%3csip%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%40&i=%22Elevator%22+%3csip%3a103%40192.168.1.1%3e%3btag%3d343483547) (Click on the Table tab)